# find and extract a sequence from a string by a special character

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing a phonenumber within a text. This phonenumber is wrapped by a special character.

**Examples:**
*The special character is '*

> Hello '12345' World
>
> Hello World '12345'
>
> '12345' Hello World

I want to process the string and an object with two properties, the phonenumber and the message text.

The example result would be

```
{
   phonenumber: "12345",
   announcement: "Hello World"
}
```

I tried to create a solution for this

```js
const identificationCharacter = "'";

const exampleText = "Hello '12345' World";

const phoneInfo = inspect(exampleText);

console.log(phoneInfo);

function inspect(text) {
  const firstIndex = text.indexOf(identificationCharacter);
  const secondIndex = text.lastIndexOf(identificationCharacter) + 1;

  const phoneString = text.substring(firstIndex, secondIndex);

  const phoneNumber = phoneString.substring(1, phoneString.length - 1);

  const announcement = text.replace(phoneString, "");

  return {
    phoneNumber,
    announcement
  }
}
```

but I don't think it's a good solution. Are there any better ways to do it?

Comment: I actually think that this is a great solution :) Ignore those regex hacks below, they are maybe shorter but definetly less maintainable...

Comment: @JonasWilms Finally a wise comment :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to a comment, I try to generalize my previous answer:

```js
function convert(input, separator = "'") {
   var regex = new RegExp(`(.*)[${separator}](.*)[${separator}](.*)`)
   return input.replace(regex, "{ phonenumber: \"$2\", announcement: \"$1$3\" }")
}

console.log(convert("Hello '12345' World"))
console.log(convert("Hello +12345+ World", '+'))
```

Comment: is it possible to use something like

`"{ phonenumber: \"$separation\", announcement: \"everything except separation\" }"`

because there might be more than 3 parts in a string

Answer (score 2):

You could also `.split` by ', then add up the last and first part:

```
 const [first, phoneNumber, last] = exampleText.split("'").map(it => it.trim());
 return {
   phoneNumber,
   anouncement: first + " " + last,
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression and take the left and right part as `announcement` and the middle part as `phonenumber`.

```js
console.log(["Hello '12345' World", "'Hello World '12345'", "'12345' Hello World"].map(s => { 
    var [, left, phonenumber, right] = s.match(/^(.*)'(.+)'(.*)$/).map(s => s.trim());
    return { phonenumber, announcement: (left + ' ' + right).trim() };
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use replace and map

```js
let str = `Hello '12345' World
    Hello World '12345'
    '12345' Hello World`

let op = []

let rep = str.replace(/'(\d+)'/gm, function(match,g1){
  op.push(g1)
  return '';
})

let final = rep.split('\n').map((e,index)=>({
  accountNumber: op[index],
  accountName: e.trim()
}))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expression: may be you can trim group values after match, but the approach works...

```js
var regex = /(.*)'(.*)'(.*)/
var input0 = "Hello '12345' World"
var result0 = input0.replace(regex, "{ phonenumber: \"$2\", announcement: \"$1$3\" }")
console.log(result0)


var input1 = "Hello World '12345'"
var result1 = input1.replace(regex, "{ phonenumber: \"$2\", announcement: \"$1$3\" }")
console.log(result1)

var input2 = "'12345' Hello World"
var result2 = input2.replace(regex, "{ phonenumber: \"$2\", announcement: \"$1$3\" }")
console.log(result2)
```

EDITED

EXPLANATION

`var regex = /(.*)'(.*)'(.*)/`

1. `/.../` defines a regular expression
2. `.*` reprentes a a string of any char and with any length
3. `(expr)` matches `expr` and makes the matched value accessible as `$i` (where `i` is the 1-based index of the `(...)`, in order of appareance
4. `"a string".replace(aRegex, "a replacement")` tryies to match `aRegex` against `"a string"`, replacing matches with `"a replacement"`, which can contain `$1`, `$2`, ...

Comment: I tried to change the identification character from ' to + and this didn't work anymore :(

Comment: This is beacuse `+` is a special character in regular expressions: if you would to use it as _the + char_, you should quote it in the regex: `[+]` is the `+` character, `+` means the previous character one ore more times... you can try with `var regex = /(.*)[+](.*)[+](.*)/`

Comment: I added a new, more general answer, providing a way to customize the desired separator and qouting it in the appropriate manner... I hope this can help you!